# Usage of java.util.ArrayList in ColdFusion

Tags: java, arrays, coldfusion, cfml

I am working on some old ColdFusion code. It probably dates from late '90s. It was programmed using

```
queryParams = createObject("java", "java.util.ArrayList");
...
arrayAppend( queryParams, {...});
...
```

It is looking like a normal array. I am wondering if someone just created a normal ColdFusion array the hard way.

Comment: Google says the `ArrayNew()` function was introduced with ColdFusion MX 6 circa 2002. I was super into Batman at the time so I'm not sure what CF devs were doing to work with Arrays prior to that.

Comment: You should write this up as an answer. I don't know if anyone will have anything better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preface this... My comment was an educated guess. The only person who could give a truly objective answer for a question like this is the champion who originally wrote the code you're looking at.

But yes, it's entirely possible (probable?) that the way people handled Arrays in Coldfusion 20 years ago would seem alien to us in modernity. `ArrayNew()` simply did not exist.

Pro Tip to anyone who reads this in the future: Adobe's help documentation usually has a "history" section that shows when functions came to be, or when they stopped being supported.

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-a-b/arraynew.html

> **ArrayNew**
>
> > History
>
> *Introduced in ColdFusion MX*

## EDIT

From the comments, I have been informed that Adobe's official page appears to be wrong. I see there are books that reference the ArrayNew function all the way back until at least ColdFusion 4 in 1999.

I suppose it's still possible that OP's code is old enough to pre-date that function since he didn't give us a version, but an interesting development nonetheless.

Comment: I'm sorry but Adobe's help file is incorrect and this is not the correct answer.  I started in ColdFusion 4.5 and I distinctly remember using arrays.  I looked up some legacy code in an application we wrote in 2002 and found `arrayNew(1)` in the code.  I then looked for an online book prior to CFMX and found a CF5 book with `arrayNew()` in it. Sorry, but arrays existed prior to CFMX. https://books.google.com/books?id=6OIdojS84l4C&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=arraynew

Comment: @user12031119 That's actually super interesting, both from a historical perspective and because it re-opens the possibilities for WTF is going on in OP's code.

Comment: Yes, this is super interesting as arrays are a standard data type that exists in every single programming language.  Also, look at it from this perspective. How could a language have an `arrayAppend()` function without an `arrayNew()` function (or some equivalent way to declare arrays)?  It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I think `createObject` was added in 4.5, but I didn't think it could deal with Java objects until CF became a JVM language. That was forever ago and early in my CF days, so I don't remember. Also, a Java Array isn't quite the same as a CF array, so would the CF Array functions have worked? I feel a little sorry for you, James. Working with _really_ legacy code sometimes needs a dev to mentally disconnect between what the code would do now and what it would have done then. And they may not be remotely similar. :-S